# copying file from one Database (SVN) to another - using what?

Tags: svn

svn info of few files in one of the directory is

### URL - /A/B/C/trunk/q/w

In another database I wanted same directory, and same files.

So my question is
Do I have to copy all the files from the org (SVN) database to mine
and then do svn add and  svn check in?

OR
I can use svn copy org database directory to my database directory?

OR something else??

Please guide...

Comment: Why don't you just check out another copy of your repository where you need it?

Comment: well, that is not possible because  original/Ref database is altogether another database. and I am working on setting up new one, which is different than org.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand why you would want to do such a thing. You want two, identical, separate, copies of your SVN database, which will both be running in production? This would defeat the point of a VCS. Or, are you trying to backup/migrate your SVN database on to another server?

Comment: second database which I am working on/setting up is not identical with another. Original database is just ref. but not same/similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can tar up and copy teh repository from one machine to another, you'll have to configure the server to know where it is.   If the two servers aren't running the same version of svn you'll want to use [svnadmin](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svnadmin.html) to [dump](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.dump.html) the repo and [load](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.load.html) it on the new machine.

I'm with Ben... I'm really not sure why you're doing what your doing.  It doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Alright - Let me take one more attempt to make it more clear. Lets say I have developed a library(huge library) for my software, now I would like to develop another library with some addition and subtraction, and for that I'll be using the same original library as a starting point,  Isn't it?? Are you agree with that..??